# Python Error: List Object Not Callable with For Loop

Tags: python, list, class, loops, typeerror

Alright so i'm having this TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

It's on the for loop below the (if type=='D')

Exact error is as follows:

```
     Traceback(most recent call last):
     file"test.py", line 55 in <module>
     main()
     File "test.py", line 49, in main
     for i in range(len(accountlist())):
     TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

My code is below, i've tried putting each parenthesis in brackets and renaming the list to something different, always getting around the same error.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
class BankAccount:

def __init__(self, getbankaccount, inputAmount=0):

    self.__balance = inputAmount

    self.__numDeposits = 0

    self.__numWithdrawals = 0

    self.__totalDeposits = 0

    self.__totalWithdrawals = 0

    self.__getbankaccount=getbankaccount

def getBalance(self):

    return self.__balance

def getNumDeposits(self):

    return self.__numDeposits

def getNumWithdrawals(self):

    return self.__numWithdrawals

def getTotalDeposits(self):

    return self.__totalDeposits

def getTotalWithdrawals(self):

    return self.__totalWithdrawals

def getbankaccount(self):

    return self.__getbankaccount

def Deposit(self,amount):

    self.__balance = self.__balance + amount

    self.__numDeposits = self.__numDeposits + 1

    self.__totalDeposits = self.__totalDeposits + amount

    return self.__balance

def Withdrawal(self,amount):

    if (self.__balance >= amount):

        self.__balance = self.__balance - amount

        self.__numWithdrawals = self.__numWithdrawals + 1

        self.__totalWithdrawals = self.__totalWithdrawals + amount

        return True

    else:

        return False


def main():
accountlist=[]

numbers=eval(input())

for i in range(numbers):

    account=input()

    amount=eval(input())

    initial=BankAccount(account, amount)

    accountlist.append(initial)

    type=input()

    while type!='#':

        if type=='D':

            account=input()

            amount=eval(input())

            for i in range(len(accountlist())):

                if(account==accountlist[i].getbankaccount()):

                    index=i

                    accountlist[index].Deposit(amount)

                    Print(amount, type, account)

        type=input()
main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that in the line `for i in range(len(accountlist())):` you have `accountlist()`.  `accountlist` is a `list`, and the `()` means you're trying to call it like you would a function.  Change the line to `for i in range(len(accountlist)):` and you should be all set.

On a sidenote, it's easy to recognize your problem from your error:

```
 TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

is telling you exactly what you need to know: that you're trying to "call" a list on line 49.  Learning to read error messages is an important and useful skill.

Comment: That fixed the TypeError, thanks a lot, but it's giving me a SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF while parsing on line 41. Which would be the first amount=eval(input()) below the first for loop, any idea what could of caused this?

Comment: @user2305960 I'm not sure why you'd need `eval` there.  `eval` is used to evaluate python code that is contained in a string.  If you're just looking for an amount from the user, I'd change that to `amount=input()`.

Comment: Isn't eval(input()) used to convert the input into an int?

Comment: @user2305960 I suppose you could do that, it'd be much safer to just do `int(input())`

Comment: Why would it be safer than eval? My professor always used eval for int inputs.

Comment: @user2305960 because there's no reason to use `eval` when you can just use `int`.  Using `eval` would mean that if you typed in something like `"__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')"` you'd tell python to execute code to delete all the files on your computer.  If you're expecting an int as input, use `int()`.  This also ensures that your code immediately fails if you pass something other than an int as input, instead of failing when you use that value later.

Comment: This kind of errors are not really well informing to be honest. Like, to derive the meaning from the error is like decrypting enigma at times.